# Django: two tables or backref parameter

Tags: django, database, model

I have two model at the moment.

```
class ServiceProvider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Services(models.Model):
    plumbing = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cleaning = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    handy_man = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    electrician = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    door_repair = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fan_install = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    service_provider = models.ForeignKey(
        ServiceProvider, related_name="ServiceProvider", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am able to get ServiceProvider from Services but how can I get Services while having ServiceProvider. Something like ServiceProvider.Services. There is a parameter in flask backref = true. It fulfill the task there but this is missing in django.

Comment: That related name makes no sense, but this is exactly what it is for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?

Comment: Not sure how to make it clearer. The related_name parameter in the foreign key is the *exact* answer to your question, but you've set it to something that doesn't make sense and hides what it does.

Comment: due to related_name="ServiceProvider" I am able to to do Service.ServiceProvider and I get the whole object that's good. Now I want things the other way round like I could do ServiceProvider.Service but django gives me an error "no attribute"

Comment: Argh. No, that is not what related_name does. `service.service_provider` is the *forward* FK, and is defined by the field name itself. To go backwards from ServiceProvider to Services you would do `service_provider.<related_name>`, which due to how you have set things up is currently `service_provider.ServiceProvider` which makes no sense. *Remove* that setting and use the default: `service_provider.services_set.all()`.

Comment: Huhhh. I guess There is a confusion let say we have a Student and couple of courses I can relation associated by having a foreign key of <pk> : student in course. I can easily get courses.student by when I say student.courses i get an error *** AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'courses'.

Comment: Yes because the default related_name is `<model>_set`. So in that case it would be `course_set`, which is a manager - so you would do `student.course_set.all()`.

Comment: Thank You So much Bro, You saved my life. Apologize for irritating.

Answer (score 0):

you can access from the related name.

```
service_provider_obj.ServiceProvider.all()
```